# Problema com relação ciclica

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma duvida: Eu tenho um utilizador que submete documentos que por sua vez são lidos por outros utilizadores. Existe algum problema neste ciclo?

[image: ERD]

Comment: Nosso idioma é o portugues, sugiro traduzir sua questao e fornecer mais mais contexto a sua duvida.

Comment: @Articuno Já editei

Comment: Coloque uma imagem que dê para ler.

Comment: document.submited_by. o user.user_id que publicou o documento ? document_read.read_by é o user.user_id que leu o documento ? Seriam diferentes , justificaria o modelo cíclico (que em geral deve ser evitado) , n~so vejos problemas no modelo

Comment: Discordo da negativa , modelo de dados publicado (modelagem é programação) e dúvida sobre modelos , modelos cíclicos.